# Boost log: Attributes vs. add_value

Tags: c++, boost-log

We are using **boost log** and want to add information about filename and line number to the logging records, similar to this question: [boost log to print source code file name and line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750218/boost-log-to-print-source-code-file-name-and-line-number). That is not a problem in itself, but there seems to be two alternative solutions: Either using attributes (as in the answer by Guillermo Ruiz) or by adding the information directly to the logging stream with add_value() as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154429/boost-log-support-file-name-and-line-number/31160870#31160870).

My question is: What are advantages/disadvantages of the two approaches when it comes to efficiency, threading, etc.? Any recommendations?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it doesn't matter if you do not plan for the attributes in question to participate in filtering. See this FAQ https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_attribute_manips_dont_affect_filters.html

Comment: Thanks! Then it seems that using add_value might be more efficient in my case, since the attributes are added only if the filter passes the log record.